# Psuedo-Tabs in android

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I want to let the user know what page of the app he is on using tabs. So if he is on page one the page one tab will be lit and if he is on page two the page two tab will be lit etc. But i want it so that the tabs don't have any function. They are stay the same across all the pages (execpt what is lit) and do not have touch/click events. Should I use tabs for this or is there a better option? How exactly do I accomplish this with tabs for the better option? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to avoid using the tab widgets altogether, and simply roll your own with TextViews arranged in a container like LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Top-level layout for page -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <!-- Tab Bar -->
  <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/tab_bar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <!-- Tab 1 -->
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_bar_file"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/file_label"/>

     <!-- Tab 2 -->
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_bar_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit_label"/>

     <!-- More tabs go here -->
   </LinearLayout>

  <!-- Page content goes here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Some notes about this:

1. You can set padding on the TextView
   to expand the tab size.  You can set a
   background drawable (including a
   color or an image resource) to
   change the 'look' of the tab, as
   well as style the text.
2. You can extract the enclosing LinearLayout for the tab bar into a
   separate XML file, and then use the
   `<include>` directive to incorporate
   it into whatever layouts need to
   display the tab.
3. In your Java code, you simply change
   the style/color of whatever tab is
   current, to highlight it for the user.